# Store expanding value list for specific key values

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

In my project i have expandable value list for specific key. And i want to store all these key value pair in local memory. I found that it will inactive if i keep them inside hashmap as there can be thousands of insertions per second. What is the best data structure available in java for this task ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I found that it will inactive if i keep them inside hashmap as there can be thousands of insertions per second."? Can you provide a [mcve] to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: If you have concerns about "there can be thousands of insertions per second." instead of data structure in Java better to check in memory data solutions like Redis.

Comment: Because if i use hashmap which contains arraylists as its values, for every insertion have to update the arraylist and put it in to hashmap which seems very inefficient

Comment: @IsharaD You won't have to put the arraylist each time you update it. You'll access the arrayList via map.get(key) and then call arraylist.add() to add new element to it.

Comment: @ka3ak oh how did i miss it thank you